# DIV fit width content in parent

Tags: html, css

I have a list of object with slider - when clicking on right arrow, *left* param animates to i.e. -500px.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="list">
      <div class="elem"></div>
      <div class="elem"></div>
      <div class="elem"></div>
      <div class="elem"></div>
      // more ...
   </div>
</div>
```

styles

```
#container {
   width: 500px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
#list {
   position: relative;
   left: 0px;
}
.item {
   float: left;
}
```

I want `#list` to fit its content - now it moves overflowed children to the next line.
Setting `display: inline-block` would work but without parent with fixed width.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can create a JS Fiddle and show us the issue as your explanation is not clear. What exactly this line means "Now it moves overflowed children to the next line"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `white-space: nowrap` to `#container` div.

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#list {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}
.item {
  float: left;
}
.elem {
  background: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="list">
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    // more ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference: [MDN - white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Answer (score 0):

If the slider is customized/created by you, and you know which slide is the active one, you can get the width of the item and set it with javascript/jquery to `#list`.

Otherwise, if the slider is downloaded, you can try to see if the active one haves an active class, and then get the width with the same method above, getting the width of the active item and set it to the parent ´#list´

Answer (score 0):

Set margin like this:

```
#list {
   margin:0px auto;
   width: 80%;
}
```

This will center the list inside container.